# How to display overNode label in Sigma.Js programmatically?

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I'm using [Sigma.Js](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js) library to display graph visualization in my Node.Js app.

There's an `overNode` event, which displays the label of the node in a white rectangle when you hover over it.

I want to display this label rectangle when the node is clicked, does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: so you want to replace overnode event with click ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek i just want the same overnode caption label to appear when the node is clicked

Comment: anyone knows what i could do?

Comment: please let me know if my solution works for you

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

1. download the source code ( as it is hard to modify the minified version ) from [**github**](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js)
2. find the file `sigma.misc.bindEvents.js` inside this path : `sigma.js-master\sigma.js-master\src\misc`
3. Open this file using a good code editor ( sublime text for example ).
4. Navigate to line `494`
5. Find this code:

> // Bind events:
>
> ```
>       captor.bind('click', onClick);
>       captor.bind('mousedown', onMove);
>       captor.bind('mouseup', onMove);
>       captor.bind('mousemove', onMove);
>       captor.bind('mouseout', onOut);
>       captor.bind('doubleclick', onDoubleClick);
>       captor.bind('rightclick', onRightClick);
>       self.bind('render', onMove);
> ```

6. change both events `"click"` & `"move"` to be as follows:

> // Bind events:
>
> ```
>       captor.bind('click', onMove);
>       captor.bind('mousedown', onMove);
>       captor.bind('mouseup', onMove);
>       //captor.bind('mousemove', onMove);
>       captor.bind('mouseout', onOut);
>       captor.bind('doubleclick', onDoubleClick);
>       captor.bind('rightclick', onRightClick);
>       self.bind('render', onMove);
> ```

7. save your js file , and now try for example testing `sigma.js-master\sigma.js-master\examples\basic.html` in your browser.

Here is an **[Example](http://prollygeek.com/sigma.js-master/sigma.js-master/examples/basic.html)**